# R2DBC - IllegalArgumentException: Cannot encode parameter of type java.util.Date

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc, r2dbc-mysql

I'm learning Reative jdbc with R2DBC MySQL. I have a repository like this:

```
public interface VerificationTokenRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<VerificationToken,Long> {
```

The VerificationToken class looks like this:

```
@Table
public class VerificationToken {

@Id
private final Long id;

@Column
private final String code;

@Column
private final Date validUntil;

@Column
private boolean used;

@Column
private Long userId;

@Column
private Long verificationTokenType;
```

The script to create the table is this one:

```
create table verification_token (
    id int unsigned not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    code varchar(36) not null,
    valid_until datetime not null,
    used boolean not null,
    verification_token_type_id int unsigned not null,
    user_id int unsigned,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    constraint verification_token_type_fk FOREIGN KEY (verification_token_type_id) REFERENCES verification_token_type(id),
    CONSTRAINT user_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(id)
);
```

When I execute the method **verificationTokenRepository.save** the console shows this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot encode parameter of type java.util.Date
    at io.r2dbc.h2.codecs.DefaultCodecs.encode(DefaultCodecs.java:73)
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ SQL "INSERT INTO verification_token (code, valid_until, used, user_id, verification_token_type) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)" [DatabaseClient]
Stack trace:
```

POM file

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- For testing possibility -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dev.miku</groupId>
        <artifactId>r2dbc-mysql</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.2.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>r2dbc-h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

How can I store a Date using R2DBC? Or if R2DBV support it?

Comment: Simple google to find the github it declares all datatypes that are supported and not date https://github.com/mirromutth/r2dbc-mysql

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Date Use Instant from import java.time.Instant package.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Use Timestamp.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE tweet (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, tweet VARCHAR(255), created TIMESTAMP, updated TIMESTAMP );
```

Repository:

```
package com.reactive.demo.reactivedemo;

import org.springframework.data.repository.reactive.ReactiveCrudRepository;
public interface  TweetRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Tweet, Long> {

}
```

Bean:

```
package com.reactive.demo.reactivedemo;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

import java.time.Instant;

public class Tweet {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    public Tweet(Long id, Instant created, Instant updated, String tweet) {
        this.id = id;
        this.created = created;
        this.updated = updated;
        this.tweet = tweet;
    }

    public Tweet() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Instant getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(Instant created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    public Instant getUpdated() {
        return updated;
    }

    public void setUpdated(Instant updated) {
        this.updated = updated;
    }

    public String getTweet() {
        return tweet;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Tweet{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", created=" + created +
                ", updated=" + updated +
                ", tweet='" + tweet + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public void setTweet(String tweet) {
        this.tweet = tweet;
    }

    private Instant created;

    private Instant updated;

    private String tweet;

}

Testting code
```

```
@Bean
public CommandLineRunner demo(TweetRepository tweetRepo){

    return (args) -> {
        
        Flux<Tweet> tweetFlux = Flux.just(new Tweet(null, Instant.ofEpochMilli(System.currentTimeMillis()),Instant.ofEpochMilli(System.currentTimeMillis()), "HEllo")).flatMap(tweetRepo::save);
        tweetFlux.thenMany((tweetRepo.findAll())).subscribe(System.out::println);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

please make sure to use `LocalDateTime` in java 8,
The error will go away.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html

According to your code,

```java
@Column
private final LocalDateTime validUntil;
```